# Contiki-ng with libcoap

Tags: ubuntu, contiki, libcoap

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS and contiki-ng installed. 
Trying to start a multicast root (provided by the cooja multicast example) in a terminal i faced the error "Failed to open tun device". The same error appeared with sink node but it solved using sudo. With root node exists in any case.
I read somewhere that I need to replace the native coap package with libcoap.
So I tried (as described in libcoap.net/install.html)

```
sudo git git@github.com:obgm/libcoap.git
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

but then I received the error "make : No targets determined and no makefile found".
Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: "git: 'git@github.com:obgm/libcoap.git'" reports "is no git-command". Check, if you cloned the repo and checked out the master by "ls". That should list some files and folders, e.g. "src" or "include".

Answer (score 0):

git, ./autogen.sh and ./configure worked ok.
The error throwed when I run "make" command.

Meanwhile a friend showed me the problem was the lack of the --disable-dtls parameter in ./configure.
Now its ok
thanks